# Using multiple instances of a component inside parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, setstate

I have a page where multiple spinners needs to be shown. The spinners should be hidden whenever data arrives.

. In the example I have child components where in I have mocked the data using a settimeout as if it were coming from the back-end.

I have extracted the loader as a separate component, so that it behaves as a common loader for all the items.

Usually the API would give me array of items if present, and if not an empty array.

Have tried some approach but 
For all the cards, it's showing not found and then gets replaced with the content

Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-table-row-table-vdnfh?codemirror=1

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import Card from "./Card";

class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cardData1: undefined,
      cardData2: undefined,
      cardData3: undefined,
      cardData4: undefined
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getGraphData();
  }

  getGraphData = () => {
    this.setGraphData("graph1");
    this.setGraphData("graph2");
    this.setGraphData("graph3");
    this.setGraphData("graph4");
  };

  setGraphData = (cardNumber: string) => {
    //based on the attribute I set the corresponding card data
    if (cardNumber === "graph1") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ cardData1: [1, 2, 3] });
      }, 1000);
    }
    if (cardNumber === "graph2") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ cardData2: [3, 4, 5] });
      }, 2000);
    }

    if (cardNumber === "graph3") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ cardData3: [6, 7, 8] });
      }, 3000);
    }
    if (cardNumber === "graph4") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ cardData4: [] });
      }, 4000);
    }
  };

  render() {
    let { cardData1, cardData2, cardData3, cardData4 } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Card
          name="Card1"
          data={this.state.cardData1}
          spinnerFlag={cardData1 === undefined}
        />
        <Card
          name="Card3"
          data={this.state.cardData2}
          spinnerFlag={cardData2 === undefined}
        />
        <Card
          name="Card3"
          data={this.state.cardData3}
          spinnerFlag={cardData3 === undefined}
        />
        <Card
          name="Card4"
          data={this.state.cardData4}
          spinnerFlag={cardData4 === undefined}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is not working? From your description and the sample... it looks like everything is working as you describe.

Comment: Hi can you please explain what the issue in more detail ? Are you saying that when data arrives there is a frame where it shows the state for no data and then renders the data? If so that is most likely an issue in the actual card component and we would need to see that. Also just a small suggestion code wise, maybe try `!cardData` instead of === undefined

Comment: Also again not to be nit picky just a suggestion for you code wise. Try not to set variables as undefined. Its best practice to leave undefined only for variables that where never given a value by the developer. Use null instead if you want to set an empty variable. Makes it easier to debug stuff.

Comment: @Viktor Garba  The issue that I am trying to solve is, I need to have a single spinner component that should take of showing and hiding the loader. I have tried to solve that in the sandbox (please refer the link in the question). With my code, the "data not found" is first shown and then data arrives. What I need instead is the spinner to be shown till data arrives and based on it i need to display the data or " data not found" should be shown if no data is present. The data that i get is either array of items or an empty array in case

Comment: @ageoff. The issue that I am trying to solve is, I need to have a single spinner component that should take of showing and hiding the loader. I have tried to solve that in the sandbox (please refer the link in the question). With my code, the "data not found" is first shown and then data arrives. What I need instead is the spinner to be shown till data arrives and based on it i need to display the data or " data not found" should be shown if no data is present. The data that i get is either array of items or an empty array in case no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah okay now I understand. So your issue is that in your card component you are rendering both the data section (that either shows the data or not found) and the spinner at the same time. You need to check if the data is still being fetched (spinnerFlag) and conditionally render the spinner or the data based on that flag.

```
        <div className="box">
          {
            this.props.spinnerFlag ? (
              <Spinner spinnerFlag={this.props.spinnerFlag} />
            ) : (
              <div>
                {data && data.length ? (
                  data.map((val: any, index: any) => (
                    <span key={index}>Value : {val} </span>
                  ))
                ) : (
                  <div>Not found</div>
                )}
              </div>
            )
          }
        </div>
```

Edit: I meant when you initialize variable just use `null` because youre actually setting the 'value'

```
this.state = {
  cardData1: null,
  cardData2: null,
  cardData3: null,
  cardData4: null
};
```

And then when you do

```
<Card
  name="Card1"
  data={this.state.cardData1}
  spinnerFlag={!cardData1}
/>
```

The `!` is an operator which basically means 'not' and will evaluate to a boolean that is the opposite of the actual variable. So if `cardData1` is `null` (falsey), `!cardData1` will be `true`. Then when data is set, it will be false.

P.S Fun trick, `!!` forces things to a boolean if you need a boolean for whatever reason

Comment: Thanks:) How would you suggest me do it since you have to told me not to use undefined? How would I achieve the same thing with your way

Comment: I expanded my answer a little! Happy to help

Comment: So  spinnerFlag={!!cardData1} need to make this change?

Comment: On no my bad, just `!cardData1`. Because if you init `cardData1 = null` that would be a false value. But since you want the spinner to show up you want to convert that to `true` if its null. So you add the `!` to get the opposite of its current value `null`. Then when `cardData = [...somedata]`, it will be a `true` value because there is an array, and the `!` will turn it into a `false` value, which will hide the spinner